# ENUM: Argument of type '"HH:MM"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormatOptions'

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, enums

I made a function that accepts two arguments data and format. I'm trying to make ENUM(FormatOptions) for argument called "format". However, here is an error:

> Argument of type '"HH:MM"' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'FormatOptions'

How to write the correct ENUM for 2nd argument?
Here is Playground on TypeScript [Click](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwgS2AFWQWwKYC4YJgCeMAvDAN4BQMMR2CATvgORgCuOjqLANDTEzgoAC1YQRIRlD4CAJgiKsATAFo5yAObIZ-WpPbMYbTtm7BZtTMg5Q8xjlx78AvgG4qVUJFgHGEAFkbdjsIfEIScmp9EENWRzNnAWtbexMnC1cPKmxHGAAxKUwEKAB5AAcoZHAISgEACVj-INTa8hZ6+twAgMsYAOERABFFAE0GRjJjHoB6IaGZ0aXR2XdPb2gYBTtCxmLYcgAKbfsRu14YADMikvxd-YqqmoBKMgA+OtpkS5hD672SmRSO1Ot1eq9orQYIxsFBDGAYGBsAB3GBnbDHErYZ4AOigIAAMiBgAgADbYADKUG4YE0hxYuVUAFUKXwYH5AsFQs8PLQXJ5aDC4YwEUjUejMXZcfiiSTyVSaXSGWBmayLogUOgsNiPGsqCd7iVDmK0ViLh0uj0WDzPEA)

Code:

```
const basicTime: any = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
};

const hoursMinutes: any = {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
};

enum FormatOptions {
  HoursMinutes = 'HH:MM',
  MonthDayYear = 'MM/DD/YYYY',
};

const dateFormat = (date: Date, format: FormatOptions) => {
  if (format === 'HH:MM') {
    return new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-US', hoursMinutes);
  }

  return new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-US', basicTime);
};

dateFormat(new Date, 'HH:MM');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `enum` you can use `union`:

```
const basicTime: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
};

const hoursMinutes: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
};


type FormatOptions = 'HH:MM' | 'MM/DD/YYYY'


const dateFormat = (date: Date, format: FormatOptions) => {
  if (format === 'HH:MM') {
    return new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-US', hoursMinutes);
  }

  return new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-US', basicTime);
};

dateFormat(new Date(), 'HH:MM');
```

Comment: This part is nice! "type FormatOptions = 'HH:MM' | 'MM/DD/YYYY'"
What is Intl before DateTimeFormatOptions  ?

Comment: Intl in this case mean namespace. It contains type DateTimeFormatOptions (it is the same as type of second argument of toLocaleString method)